# What is the relevant way to show share count of article?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, sharing

The share count on the left bottom of image is the total share count of story and I placed there because that was near to sharing button so that this will make more sense, but I have a confusion, that user assume it as a share count of only image.

Is this relevant way to show whole story share count?

There is also a confusion in my mind that the text written on right bottom of image is the caption separately for image, then how the other element can represent whole article.

[image]

Comment: Why would someone be interested in the number of times something has been shared? In any case if you put the count on the image then gestalt theory states that user will assume the count is related to the image. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology#Gestalt_and_Design

Comment: Share counts indicates to the user that story is popular among user and trending even it motivates the user to share the same.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you show share count with **Social Media** In my site i have experience on this social sharing count like this[image]

if you used WordPress you can try **#1 WordPress plugins** sumome! Thank you